# Need details on 35-year old Unisonic VFD (from a calculator)

Tags: display, 7segmentdisplay

I have a very old Vacuum Fluorescent Display that I took out of a Unisonic Calculator, that I'd like to resurrect in a clock.

It's a cylindrical glass tube, about 4 inches long and 1/2 inch wide - with roughly 10 digits and about 15 wires coming out of it.

Is there a good way to determine which wires are which?  Other post suggest that they work somewhat like vacuum tubes, so different voltage and currents are needed for the various wires.

I'd hate to connect the wrong wires to the wrong voltage and blow it up.  The calculator was a Unisonic 700 or 800 series calculator from the mid-1970s.

Comment: Can you post a picture of this tube? It's somewhat straightforward if the inside electrodes are visible.

Comment: I have interfaced that calculator with the VFD display to 1" large LED digits to use a a calorie down-counter for stationary running in 1977. I cannot remember the pin #s but it similar to an LED common anode display except runs on higher DC-DC V+ which I want to say was around 25V.

If you have any information to identify the pins in any way, that would help. But interfacing may be a matter of using open collector drivers for segments to pull down and PNP open collector drivers to pull up to the V+ of 25V or so required in a common anode with 7 seg plus dot(s).

Comment: Is this it http://www.devidts.com/be-calc/desk_12184.html ?

Comment: Photos:  http://mycalcdb.free.fr/main.php?l=0&id=2688

Tony, unfortunately it isn't, it's a single cylindrical tube with about 10-15 wires coming out of one side:  The Unisonic 790R (not to be confused with the 790RM, which has a different display) seems very close in design, based on the photos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hack this, just identify the filament pins: measure with a VOM (not on ohms x1 scale, that might blow the filament) until you find two that are nearly shorted. Since you know what batteries were in the original calculator, the filament is likely to take 1.5v, maybe more (Google to see if there is any standard). Once you have a possible ID on that, feed it a controlled current (about 10-20 mA) in a dark place and watch closely for a fine line getting dull red as you increase the current. Don't go any higher, it's designed to run at sub-luminal temperature. If there is more than one pair that could be the filament, try all the permutations until you have it. (There is a slight chance that it is tapped, so three pins may connect to the filament.) Some pins may be simply shorted together and not go to the filament.
Once you have the filament, feed it a current just below the visible level, and while doing so connect about +15 volts through about 10K to each of the other pins and watch for segments that light up. Draw a diagram of which pin lights which segment.
After that, experiment with the segment voltage and resistance for adequate brightness.
It's a lot of work but it may be the only way to get this done.